# Powershell script to verify IIS Settings

Tags: windows, powershell, iis

Is it to possible to get IIS settings using Power Shell Script?

I am looking to get/check below information using a a script:

1. Check if Windows Authentication Providers are listed correctly (Negotiate, NTLM)
2. Check if Windows Authentication is enabled
3. Windows Authentication Advanced Settings -> enable kernel-mode is on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is all easily possible with PowerShell. There are lots of samples and examples online.

Look at the [(IIS) Administration Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh867899(v=wps.630).aspx)
and especially [Get-WebConfiguration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh867868(v=wps.630).aspx) and [Get-WebConfigurationProperty](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh867890(v=wps.630).aspx).

To get information about the Windows Authentication Advanced Settings use:

```
$windowsAuthFilter = "/system.WebServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication"
$winKernel = (Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'Default Web Site' -filter "$windowsAuthFilter" -name "useKernelMode").Value
$winKernel 
$winProviders = Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'Default Web Site' -filter "$windowsAuthFilter/providers" -name "." 
$winProviders.Collection | Format-Table value
```

Comment: Tried:

    Import-Module WebAdministration
    cd IIS:
    IIS:\>Get-WebConfiguration -Filter     "System.WebServer/Security/Authentication/* /*" -Recurse | where {$_.enabled -eq $True} | Format-List
'
But get an error as below:
IIS:\>Get-WebConfiguration : The term 'IIS:\>Get-WebConfiguration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Run `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerManagementTools` to install the IIS cmdlets, if you have an older Windows version, installed them via the GUI.

Comment: The below code runs fine but in the output it doesn't shows if Windows Authentication is enabled or not for IIS:
    Get-WebConfiguration     system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication/* 'IIS:\sites\Default Web Site' -Recurse | format-list

Answer (score 1):

Below is the answer to read anonymous and windows authentication:

```
$anonAuthFilter =    "/system.WebServer/security/authentication/AnonymousAuthentication"
$windowsAuthFilter = "/system.WebServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication"

$value = 'false'
$AppName = "test"

$anonAuth = Get-WebConfigurationProperty -filter $anonAuthFilter -name Enabled -location $AppName
Write-Host  $anonAuth.Value


$winAuth = Get-WebConfigurationProperty -filter $windowsAuthFilter -name Enabled -location $AppName
Write-Host  $winAuth.Value
```

@Peter Hahndorf 
Still didn't find any clue for

Check Windows Authentication Advanced Settings -> enable kernel-mode is on and

Check check Enabled Providers like NTLM and Negotiate