# IIS Command To Get Status Of Anonymous Access and Authentication Control

Tags: powershell, authentication, iis, command

Under the authentication section of IIS, I am trying to check if anonymous access is enabled or disabled via command line, I have crafted the following command, but it seems to not be grabbing the setting correctly:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'Default Web Site' -filter "system.webServer/asp" -name "anonymousAuthentication" | select enabled
```

Is anyone able to help me, please?

Comment: Why `system.webServer/asp`? Please study the configuration reference first, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command.

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'Default Web Site' -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication" -name "enabled" | select value
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$anonAuthFilter = '/system.WebServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication'
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'Default Web Site' -filter $anonAuthFilter -name Enabled
```

Stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38722666/18815893)

The reason is that authentication settings are configured at the server level using location tags, per a [blog post I found](https://blogs.iis.net/jeonghwan/examples-of-iis-powershell-cmdlets)

Note that the property is actually called `Enabled`.